# Can linux cat command be used for writing text to file?

Tags: linux, cat

Is something like this:

```
cat "Some text here." > myfile.txt
```

Possible? Such that the contents of `myfile.txt` would now be overwritten to:

```
Some text here.
```

This doesn't work for me, but also doesn't throw any errors.

Specifically interested in a `cat`-based solution (not vim/vi/emacs, etc.). All examples online show `cat` used in conjunction with file inputs, not raw text...

Answer (score 280, accepted):

That's what `echo` does:

```
echo "Some text here." > myfile.txt
```

Comment: Bonus: `echo "Some text here." >> myfile.txt` to append to the end o the file

Comment: If you need to use double quotes in your text, encompass the whole thing in single quotes. This is useful for .json and the likes, e.g. `echo '{"info1": "123456"}' > info.json`

Answer (score 235):

Sounds like you're looking for a [Here document](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document)

```
cat > outfile.txt <<EOF
>some text
>to save
>EOF
```

Comment: On linux Kernel 2.6.32 centos 6 I had to omit the `>` characters to get expected output.

Comment: The `>` characters represent the default value of `$PS2`; they show up automatically, and are not meant to be typed. If you have a different value for `$PS2`, that will show up instead.

Comment: Whats the `<<EOF` syntax do?

Comment: `<<EOF` is starting the here doc and indicating the end string. The linked wikipedia page describes it.

Answer (score 81):

Here's another way -

```
cat > outfile.txt
>Enter text
>to save press ctrl-d
```

Answer (score 36):

For text file:

```
cat > output.txt <<EOF
some text
some lines
EOF
```

For PHP file:

```
cat > test.php <<PHP
<?php
echo "Test";
echo \$var;
?>
PHP
```

Answer (score 14):

I use the following code to write raw text to files, to update my CPU-settings. Hope this helps out!
Script:

```
#!/bin/sh

cat > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor <<EOF
performance
EOF

cat > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_governor <<EOF
performance
EOF
```

This writes the text "performance" to the two files mentioned in the script above. This example overwrite old data in files.

This code is saved as a file (cpu_update.sh) and to make it executable run:

```
chmod +x cpu_update.sh
```

After that, you can run the script with:

```
./cpu_update.sh
```

IF you do not want to overwrite the old data in the file, switch out

```
cat > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_governor <<EOF
```

with

```
cat >> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_governor <<EOF
```

This will append your text to the end of the file without removing what other data already is in the file.

Answer (score 11):

```
cat > filename.txt
```

enter the text
until EOF
for save the text use : ctrl+d

if you want to read that .txt file use

```
cat filename.txt
```

and one thing .txt is not mandatory, its for your reference.

Answer (score 6):

You can do it like this too:

```
user@host: $ cat<<EOF > file.txt
$ > 1 line
$ > other line
$ > n line
$ > EOF
user@host: $ _
```

I believe there is a lot of ways to use it.

Answer (score 6):

**Write multi-line text with environment variables using `echo`:**

```
echo -e "
Home Directory: $HOME \n
hello world 1 \n
hello world 2 \n
line n... \n
" > file.txt
```

Answer (score 6):

The Solution to your problem is :

> echo  " Some Text Goes Here " > filename.txt

But you can use cat command if you want to redirect the output of a file to some other file or if you want to append the output of a file to another file :

cat filename > newfile  -- To redirect output of filename to newfile

cat filename >> newfile -- To append the output of filename to newfile

Answer (score 5):

Another way to write text to file using cat would be something like this

```
cat >file.txt <<< Write something here
```

Comment: This command is really useful when you're trying to write an output of a command into a file. For instance `cat > docker-inspect.txt <<< `docker inspect image` `

Answer (score 4):

simply pipeline echo with cat

For example

```
echo write something to file.txt | cat > file.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

`cat` can also be used following a `|` to write to a file, i.e. pipe feeds cat a stream of data

Answer (score 0):

For my Jenkins on MacOS 11.4

```
{
   echo 'line 1' $var1
   echo 'line 2'
   echo 'result' $var5

} > ${destination_file}
```

I had tried many times by `cat` syntax, ex: `cat > ${dest_file} <<EOF ... EOF`, and got error `syntax error: unexpected end of file`. So, I use `echo` syntax to output multi-lines text to a file.

#### References:

- [How to append multiple lines to a file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/437216/40123)
- [github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2129](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2129)

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody else answered the original question.  Yes. `cat` can be used to write text to a file without a here doc.

```
cat - >file.txt
This is the world's worst
multiline text editor.
^d
```